# Как активировать профиль загрузки Spring при запуске из IntelliJ?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Не могу активировать профиль загрузки Spring в IntelliJ IDEA.

Java 17

```
<spring.version>5.3.9</spring.version>
```

Захожу Run | Edit Configurations... и в VM options прописываю

```
-Dspring.profiles.active=development
```

И при запуске приложения из IDE вылетает такая ошибка:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class VM
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: VM
```

При этом вручную у меня получилось запустить с такой опцией:

```
java -jar main-ms-1.2-SNAPSHOT.jar --spring.profiles.active=development
```

Что мне еще нужно прописать в IDE, что я упустил?
Почистил кеш. Перепроверил все настройки. Ни чего не помогает. Я не пойму в чем может быть проблема. При этом у других разработчиков проекта этой проблемы нет. С флагом -Dspring.profiles.active=development приложение запускается в IDEA

The bounty expires in 4 days. Answers that other users post to this question are eligible for a +50 reputation bounty. alex is looking for a canonical answer:
I need to launch an application from IDEA
I can't activate the Spring download profile in IntelliJ IDEA.

Java 17

IntelliJ IDEA 2021.3 Beta (Ultimate Edition)

<spring.version>5.3.9</spring.version>
I'm coming in Run | Edit Configurations... and in VM options I prescribe

-Dspring.profiles.active=development
And when you start the application from the IDE, the following error crashes:

Error: Could not find or load main class VM
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: VM
At the same time, I managed to launch it manually with this option:

java -jar main-ms-1.2-SNAPSHOT.jar --spring.profiles.active=development
What else do I need to register in the IDE that I missed? I cleaned the cache. Rechecked all the settings. Nothing helps. I don't understand what the problem might be. At the same time, other project developers do not have this problem. With the -Spring.profiles.active=development flag, the application is launched in IDEA

profile in Pom.xml This is a shared file Pom.xml, which is at the root of the entire project on microservices.

development
      
        true
      
      
        development
        file:${project.basedir}/../../../maven
        ${maven.file.path}/releases
        ${maven.file.path}/snapshots
        
        localhost:5000
        http://${docker.registry.domain}
      
    

Expand snippet
And this is the file pom.xml the microservice I'm trying to run.
  
    
      com.asvoip.ump
      ump-it-lib
      1.1-SNAPSHOT
      test
    
    
      com.asvoip.ump
      ump-currencymanager-api
      1.2-SNAPSHOT
    
    
      com.asvoip.ump
      ump-sqldbclient-lib
      1.2-SNAPSHOT
    
    
      com.asvoip.ump
      ump-restapiserver-lib
      1.1-SNAPSHOT
    
    
      com.asvoip.ump
      ump-documentation-lib
      1.1-SNAPSHOT

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
  <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-web -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-sleuth</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>de.codecentric</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-admin-starter-client</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
  <artifactId>springfox-boot-starter</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>co.elastic.logging</groupId>
  <artifactId>logback-ecs-encoder</artifactId>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.projectlombok/lombok -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
  <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

io.fabric8
        docker-maven-plugin
      
    
  
Expand snippet
enter image description here enter image description here

File application.yaml

```
spring.config.activate.on-profile: development
```

Вот здесь для этого микросервиса прописал настройки, его же и пытаюсь запустить.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Приложите скриншот окна Edit Configurations либо весь текст самой первой строчки  (до Connected to the target VM) из вывода при запуске

Answer (score 1):

Ты упустил что по умолчанию IDEA грузит свой собственный JVM, и её пофигу на ENV значение что в JAVA_HOME... Когда ты грузишь с консоли то JAVA_HOME идёт от аппереционки. А исправляется достаточно просто в Project Properties добавляешь свою джаву и уже играя от неё грузишь проект.

Comment: Что значит в Project Properties добавляешь свою Java?
В Properties везде указана Java 17
Я добавляю этот флаг в Run-> Edit Configuration

Comment: Уточните какие именно Properties вы имеете ввиду. В IDEA в нескольких местах в настройках проекта указывается версия Java. Везде указана. Может я что-то пропустил.

Answer (score 0):

Установите java 8 на свой пк далее запустите через командную строку с помощью javac.если запускается то установите java в свою idea  там по умолчанию стоит своя версия .

Comment: Дело в том, что проект переделан под Java 17. Он уже не запустится в Java 8. В том то и проблема, пока мы не перешли на Java 17 и Spring 5.3 с запуском не было ни каких проблем. А начиная с 5-ой версии Spring  появились эти профайлы. Правда у других все прекрасно запускается. Эта проблемы только у меня.